# Dockerize a web app (WAR) is a good practise?

Tags: java, spring, docker, tomcat

Currently my web application (`java` + `spring` + `maven` project) is being generated in `WAR` format and deployed in a `Docker` container running `Tomcat`.

My questions are:

- Is it a good practice to have a container with Tomcat and a WAR deployed?
- Would it be possible to deploy a web application in JAR format without Tomcat to make it lighter? Is it advisable?

I've tried to **run it as a JAR** - `java -jar mypersonalproject.jar`
but I need to **define the manifest** getting this error:
`no main manifest attribute, in mypersonalproject.jar`. The problem is that I don't know which is the main class (I've tried to search the main, but there is only one in a Test class).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good practice to have a container with Tomcat and a WAR deployed?

This is likely opinion-based. Containers are expected to be able to start as quickly as possible, and not weight too much, that's why it might feel a bit contradictory to use Tomcat inside Docker *but* I wouldn't say it's a bad practice. A Tomcat server can start quickly.

> Would it be possible to deploy a web application in JAR format without Tomcat to make it lighter? Is it advisable?

Yes it's possible. You'll still need a webserver to expose your application though. One popular way is to "embed" the webserver (Jetty or Netty for instance). Some frameworks can do that for you "automatically" like Spring Boot.